# android code: clarify button clicking facebook url must display

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

friends i have written the code for to display facebook url of apple.
I have used fragment in my code

```
package com.coded.sandeep;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class BioFragment extends Fragment {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bio, container, false);

    return rootView;
}}
```

to this above code i have to add  button clicked event so i have added like this below but it:

is not working i am not able to use onclick event correctly can anyone help me to modify the code

```
package com.coded.sandeep;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_am, container, false);

    return rootView;
}}  
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ImageButton amelia_facebook = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_am);
        amelia_facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Facebook.class));
            }

        });

    }}
```

please help me in to above code as i new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize in `onCreateview`

```
ImageButton btnEnter = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook1);
```

And move the code related to `onCreateView`. The button probably belongs to fragment layout

Secondly you inflate `activity_main.xml`. I am not sure if you inflate the right layout coz it looks like the layout belongs to `MainActivity`.

Edit:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_am, container, false);
    ImageButton amelia_facebook = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_am);
    amelia_facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Facebook.class));
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: but i have using animation here pal @Raghunanadan wait i will post the code

Comment: can u check this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781627/android-code-i-have-coded-for-youtube-url-but-i-cant-play-videos-inside-my-app/22781697?noredirect=1#comment34739865_22781697

Comment: @SandeepV do accept this answer first. i will check that question

Comment: checked it @Raghunandan